# Wordpress prefixing all embedded URLs within the post with base website URL

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, url-rewriting

For example, in my post I want to direct the readers to my LinkedIn page, I do the following:

```
    Please join our <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/groups/mygroup">LinkedIn group</a>
```

What this does in reality is create a URL pointing to:

```
    http://www.mywebsite.com/%22http://www.linkedin.com/groups/mygroup/%22
```

I have a feeling that the issue is related to URL rewrite but could not find anything concrete with that.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

Try it out with just one quote:

```
Please join our <a href='http://www.linkedin.com/groups/mygroup'>LinkedIn group</a>
```

I've had this issue before and found something in the url rewrite, but have to do a search for it. Avoiding double quotes did the trick for me.

Comment: Thanks Jordan. I tried it earlier but it does not seem to work. I was wondering if there could be some prefix to the string like how '@' is used in C# (@"any string") to avoid manually escaping each special character...